# How to fetch a value from build.sbt in terminal

Tags: scala, sbt

Can anyone suggest, Through terminal how to read a value(I want to read a variable called 'version') which is present in build.sbt? I could not find any solution on the internet. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with read a value inside a `build.sbt` in the terminal? What is your use case?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html) on making new tasks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sbt v1.3.0 has a new [`print`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/4341) command, it's similar to `show` but prints directly to *standard out*:

```sh
sbt --no-colors --error 'print ThisBuild / version'
```

- `--no-colors` disables ANSI color codes
- `--error` sets the logging level to only report errors (no `[info]` and `[warn]` log messages)
- `print ThisBuild / version` is the actual command

You might want to replace `ThisBuild` by the name of your project.

If you have a multi-project and the root one aggregates tasks, then you might get version output for every subproject. To turn that off you can use the `aggregate` setting:

```sh
sbt --no-colors --error 'set aggregate := false; print version'
```

Notice that this command takes time, it might appear that nothing is happening, but it's just sbt loading silently (because we turned off the logs).

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the value `1.0.0` from line `ThisBuild / version := "1.0.0"` of your build.sbt you can use the following shell command.

```
grep "ThisBuild / version" build.sbt | cut -d\" -f2
```

Comment: The above command gives all the string where ever version is there. I wanted to pick only version:)